# Can't get Promise to work with Trello in Ionic2 typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, trello

Problem is that I want to ensure data is available before I proceed through my program, so I need to use async type function. Promise seems to be standard method as per ionic.io.

I have a very simple example below which basically comes from the Trello.com website to make a card. I then load the id into a global array and then attempt to log it.

//Start of myTry.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
//compile needs this and it seems to make the Trello functions work
declare var Trello: any;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/mytry/mytry.html'
})
export class MyTryPage {
    fileEntry: any;
    myData: any;    
    myList: any = "MyList ID - get this from the sandbox screen in Trello.com please";

    newCard = {     
        name: '****My New Test Card', 
        desc: '****This is the description of our new card.',
        idList: this.myList,
        pos: 'top'
    };

    readTrello: any = function() {
        Trello.post('/cards/', this.newCard, this.creationSuccess);
    }

    constructor(private navController: NavController) {

        Trello.authorize({
            type: "redirect",
            interactive: "true",
            name: "My Application",
            scope: {
                read: "true",
                write: "true" },
            expiration: "never",
            success: this.authenticationSuccess,
            error: this.authenticationFailure
        });

        this.testPromise();

        // this line does not work
        console.log('My data ' + this.myData); // returns undefined

     }

    testPromise: any = function () {    
        var p1 = new Promise( resolve => {
            this.readTrello();
            window.setTimeout( () => {
                // this line is run after timeout completes so why is data not available
                console.log("Since this is run after timeout, I expect data to exist???? "+ this.myData);
                resolve(0);
            }, 5000);
        });

        p1.then(
            // Log the fulfillment value
            () => {
                    //This fails - data is NOT available
                    console.log('Promise fullfilled. Data should be available:???? Array is no longer in scope at all????' + this.myData);

                    // I will load into displayable structure here later

                })
        .catch(
            // Log the rejection reason
            function(reason) {
                console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
            });
    }



    authenticationSuccess: any = function() {
        //This works
        console.log("Successful authentication"); 
    };
    authenticationFailure: any = function() {
        console.log("Failed authentication");
    };

    creationSuccess: any = function(data) {
        //This works
        console.log('Trello callback successfull');
        this.myData = JSON.stringify(data.id);
        //This works and the data returned is available and correct - great.
        console.log('Card created successfully. Data returned:' + this.myData);
    };

}
```

I am missing something - data is available before timeout but not after ??? Obviously my program flow is incorrect.
ps I can do above using tokens but I want to use the Trello published APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use lambda functions if you want the `this` keyword to be defined as you're using it inside that function body.

Instead of `window.setTimeout( function() {` use `window.setTimeout(() => {`

Do the same thing for the `p1.then` line.

Also, in this line: `Trello.post('/cards/', this.newCard, this.creationSuccess);` instead of passing `this.creationSuccess` try passing `this.creationSuccess.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks Paarth, I replaced as I think your were advising to make them lambda functions but got same result when I ran code. Data is available in callback but not later on. I assume my data is not in scope.

Comment: I also added a console.log line to the constructor to see if myData is available - its not. Perhaps there is also a problem how I have declared myData.

Comment: in this line: `Trello.post('/cards/', this.newCard, this.creationSuccess);
` instead of passing `this.creationSuccess` try passing `this.creationSuccess.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks Paarth - You solved it perfectly. Thats fantastic. This means for all the ionic2 developers who want to access Trello boards and cards, they do not need to pass the token as text. How do i close this question please.

Comment: @Tonyeng my pleasure, I updated the answer with the text from the comment. Accepting the answer will 'close' the question.